# How to join 3 tables in linq and get some not included fields in query

Tags: linq, asp.net-core

I'm implementing asp.net core project. I have 3 tables Apiapp, ApiAppHistory and EntityType. There are three fields with the names SentType, Status and Reason in ApiAppHistory and those fields are of kind Id (int type) in APIApphistory. I joined ApiApp and ApiAppHistory tables in order to get those three fields from ApiAppHistory but because they are of kind int and are unclear when showing the result to the user, I join them with EntityType table which has their related name. In the select part of my query, in addition to ApiApp fields I also need to have SentType, Status and Reason value fields. 
Here below is my incomplete query:

```
  var qq = _context.Apiapp
           .Include(a => a.Api)
           .Include(a => a.Application)
           .Include(a => a.Data);

  var t12 = (from r in qq
                   from b in _context.ApiAppHistory
                   from s in _context.EntityType
                   where r.LastRequest== b.Id && b.SentType == s.Id 
   && b.Reason == s.Id
                   && b.Status == s.Id
                    select new { r, s.name for Reason, s.name for 
 SentType ,s.name for Status});
```

I want in select part of my query, obtain name of the fields that I specified from the EntityType table. However, I don't know how to do it. I appreciate if someone helps me.

Here is my EntityType table:

[image]

Here are my APIAppHistory and EntityType class model:

```
public partial class ApiAppHistory
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? SentType { get; set; }
        public int? Reason { get; set; }
        public int? Status { get; set; }


        public virtual Apiapp ApiApp { get; set; }
        public virtual EntityType StatusNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual EntityType SentTypeNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual EntityType ReasonNavigation { get; set; }
    }

 public partial class EntityType
    {
        public EntityType()
        {
            ApiAppHistoryStatusNavigation = new HashSet<ApiAppHistory>();
            ApiAppHistorySentTypeNavigation = new HashSet<ApiAppHistory>();
            ApiAppHistoryReasonNavigation = new HashSet<ApiAppHistory>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string EntityKey { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ApiAppHistory> ApiAppHistoryStatusNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ApiAppHistory> ApiAppHistorySentTypeNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ApiAppHistory> ApiAppHistoryReasonNavigation { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't clear. When should key be "Reason" or "SentType" or "Status"?

Comment: There are three fields in APIAppHistory with the names: SentType, Reason and Status. They are of ID kind that their names refer to EntityType name field. I want to join APIApp and APIAppHistory to get those three fields, however, because they are of int type in APIAppHistory then I should join its table with EntityType as well to get their name.

Comment: we don't use key from EntityType in the query. The key values in EntityType are just for clarifying the meaning to the developer.

Comment: Still not really clear. How can you bring the content from three fields back to one column? It would help toe see the classes. Also, why don't you use navigation properties instead of joining?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm amaetuer in asp.net core and I don't know how to query using navigation properties instead of joining. I appreciate your help

Comment: Why three fields?

Comment: Beacuse they are different with each other. They are not relevant to each other. I stored their name in another table (EntityType) because all the columns in all of my tables that has special meaning has its name in EntityType table.